# How to grab ID from multiple selected checkbox's on submit? Ionic 2+ / Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm having trouble getting the id of the checked item on submit. I'm able to retrieve the selected id on change but not on submit. Note - the data that I'm getting back does not have a checked value. So there might be a way to push a selected value into the data structure but unsure how to do so.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="itemForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(itemForm)">
    <ion-list >
      <div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-checkbox formControlName="selectAll" (click)="checkAll()" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" ></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item> 

    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-label>
        {{item.text}}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [checked]="selectedAll" formControlName="recvd" value="item.id" (ionChange)="select(item)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>

      </div>
        <button ion-button full type="submit"></button>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

TS

```
export class MessagesPage {
selectedAll: boolean = false;
 items: [];

constructor(){}

submit(form){

  console.log(form.value, 'FORMVALUE HERE') // this returns true

}

select(item){

  console.log(item) //this returns the selected item on change with the id
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ionic, perhaps its different here, but in pure angular, if you tried to set the 'value' attribute as  value="item.id", it wouldn't bind it, it would just set its value to a string literal equal to the string "item.id" (i.e, not the property of the item object called id, just a string). I think you'd have to use interpolation or attribute binding to make it bind correcly. 

[value]="item.id" or value="{{item.id}}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the answer above I was actually able to figure it out with creating a formbuilder array with the id's as objects. And used the ion-change value to grab the id. I appreciate the feedback!

TS

```
this.itemForm = formBuilder.group({
  receivedItems: this.formBuilder.array([])
})

select(item: Items, isChecked: boolean){
  const receivedItems = <FormArray>this.itemForm.controls.receivedItems;

  if(isChecked) {
    receivedItems.push(new FormControl(item));

  } else {
      let index = receivedItems.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.id == item.id);
      receivedItems.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="itemForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(itemForm)">
            <ion-list >
              <div>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-checkbox formControlName="selectAll" (click)="checkAll()" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" ></ion-checkbox>
              </ion-item> 

            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
                <ion-label>
                {{item.text}}
                </ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox [checked]="selectedAll" value="item" (ionChange)="select(item, $event.checked)"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>

              </div>
                <button ion-button full type="submit"></button>
            </ion-list>
          </form>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can show the latest `html` code too?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you used both `formControlName` and `ngModel`? But you can do it using `ngModel` as shown below.You need to have a `boolean` property like `checked` on your `items` array.

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ion-label>
        {{item.text}}
        </ion-label>
       <ion-checkbox checked="false" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" (ionChange)="select(item)"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
```